# Nginx conf erratic behaviour with Cakephp

Tags: nginx, cakephp, nginx-config

I try to access to my cakephp project with my nginx config file.
I have a 404 page not found with this config :

```
 root   /app;
 index  index.php;

 location /--redacted--/webroot/ {
      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
      }
      if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
      }

      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
```

After reading multiples solutions, on multiple websites, I tried to put it as root and my index page works. Nginx config file looks like that then :

```
root   /app/--redacted--/webroot;
index  index.php;

location / {
      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
      }
      if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
      }

      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
```

The rest of the config file is the same in the cases. I search to understand why the behaviour of Nginx is so erratic. Why the first case doesn't work ?
(Sorry if this is a repeated question ^^')

Comment: Why is it erratic? The first config places the `index.php` file at the pathname `/app/index.php`. The second config places the `index.php` file at the pathname `/app/--redacted--/webroot/index.php`. Presumably the second pathname is the correct one.

Comment: The cakephp project is in the same folder.

Second case : localhost/login is fine.
First case : localhost/--redacted--/login is not found, http error 404#6. 

This is what I don't understand. The two paths should work. But I have the impression nginx have a problem of rewrite_rule.

If I could have an explanation, that would be nice :)

Comment: Http requests with the two cases : https://annuel2.framapad.org/p/9fcf-r7y1dt5zh0

Comment: In the first case you should be rewriting with something like `rewrite ... /--redacted--/webroot/index.php?... last;` as that is the correct URI for `index.php` with the value for `root` that you have used.